# Radio buttons not passing any value

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am using two simple radio buttons and trying to pass values and then use $_POST variable to read the value but the value being set is empty

```
<form style="text-align:left;margin-left:80px;" class="form-inline signup" role="form" method="post" action="userdet.php">
<div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom:7px;">
<input type="text" name="first" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
<input type="text" name="last" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom:7px;">
<input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Your Email" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom:7px;">
<input type="email" name="re-email" class="form-control" placeholder="Re-enter Email" />
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom:7px;">
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="New Password" />
</div>
<span class="help-block">Birthday</span>
<div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom:7px;">
<select name="day" class="form-control" style="width:100px">
<?php
for($i=1;$i<=31;$i++)
{
    echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}
?>
</select>


<select name="month"  class="form-control">
<option value="January">January</option>
<option value="February">February</option>
<option value="Mars">March</option>
<option value="April">April</option>
<option value="May">May</option>
<option value="June">June</option>
<option value="July">July</option>
<option value="September">September</option>
<option value="October">October</option>
<option value="November">November</option>
<option value="December">December</option>
</select>

<select name="year" class="form-control" style="width:120px">
<?php
for($i=1980;$i<=2015;$i++)
{
    echo '<option value='.$i.'>'.$i.'</option>';
}

?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" style="padding-bottom:7px;">
    <label class="radio inline" ><input type="radio" style="visibility:hidden;margin-left:-70px" value="not specified" name="gender" checked/></label>
    <label class="radio inline" ><input type="radio" value="female" name="gender" />Female</label>
    <label class="radio inline"><input type="radio" value="male" name="gender" />Male</label>

</div>
<div class="form-group" style="margin-top:12px;">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
</div>
</form>
```

`$_POST['gender']` variable is set but has empty value even if radio is checked.All other post variables are working properly.

In php code I'm just printing the values for now using echo one by one .

What maybe wrong in this code ?

Comment: Are you sure the form is doing a POST and not a GET?  Try changing to $_REQUEST['gender'].  Just a thought.  You should post your entire form html

Comment: @Tom Gerken  tried REQUEST same result as before..

Comment: One common problem is with htaccess rewrite rules causing POST data to be lost. Just something to check out.

Comment: Show us your PHP handler. The problem is not in your "posted" code. At least not without seeing your handler.

Comment: it is just 

echo ($_POST['gender']); 

same for other variables..

Comment: Ok and does your handler contain `$gender=$_POST['gender'];`? which you could just do `echo $gender;`

Comment: @Fred-ii- tried this too but there is no change

Comment: I tested part of your code and found nothing wrong with it. So the error obviously lies in your handler which you fail to show us/me. Doing `echo ($_POST['gender']);` is not reliable. You should be using the method I've given you above. See my pastebin file http://pastebin.com/fd5X9Q8a

Comment: @Fred-ii- I tried using your method but the variable has an empty string .

Comment: My pastebin file works, I tested it. So again, it's something inside your handler that's messing with you. Then try using `name="gender[]"` for all of them, see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Same here, I tried with `echo $_POST['gender']` and everything is working ok

Answer (score 0):

Try by changin the name to 'gender[]', this would be using an array..
Then capture it in a variable for example:$gender = $_POST['gender'];
and then to echo the value you can use something like is:

```
if(is_array($gender)){  
    foreach ($gen as $gender){
    echo $gender."<br />";

    }
}
```

It worked for me!

Answer (score -2):

Try to change

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">Sign Up</button>
```

to

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit" value="Sign Up">
```

Comment: Submit is working properly and doing this change does not make a difference

Comment: This would only make a difference if the server side code was testing the value of `$_POST['submit']`, but since *All other post variables are working properly* it isn't related to the problem.

Comment: @SayanPaul Then let us know about code that you are using to process data from form.